# jQuery: how to style background color of a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to develop a website using `jQuery`.
I have this code:

```
$(function () {
       $(".myButton").click(function() {
           alert("You clicked button!");
       });
   });
```

How do I change the background color of the class `myButton`?

Comment: um https://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: I really cannot believe there was no answer on Google

Answer (score 1):

You can use `this` keyword to change its background color like this.

```js
$(function () {
     $(".myButton").click(function() {
         $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
     });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="myButton" type="button" >Click me</button>
<button class="myButton" type="button" >Click me</button>
<button class="myButton" type="button" >Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `$(this)`

```js
$(function() {
  $(".myButton").click(function() {
    $(this).css("background", "red")
    alert("You clicked button!");
  });
});
```

```html
<button class="myButton">button</button>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it with jQuery, then it's:

```js
$(".myButton")
  .css("background-color", "green")
  .css("color", "white")
  .css("border-radius", "5px")
  .css("font-family", "roboto")
  .css("border", "none")
  .click(function(){
    $(this).css("background-color", "red");
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="myButton">Click Me</button>
```